# Compare row name with one cell in sql

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables. One table with a id, date, menu1, menu2, menu3 and another table with a id, id_date, number, menu_number.

In the second table there is data about users who have ordered a menu in a specific day. So example: ID: 1 ID_Date: 2014-09-09 Number: 4000 Menu_Number: Menu1. And with this Information I want to give out the Number, the date and the menu on this date which stands in the first table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    B.ID, B.ID_Date, B.Menu, S.date 
FROM 
    ordering B, menu_plan S 
WHERE 
    B.ID_Date = S.Date 
    AND B.Number = '4000859'
```

This SQL statement only gives me the menu number for a specific day. But I want the content from the menu on this specific day from table 1. How does it work? Or should I do it in another way and write in the second table instead of the menu number the full menu?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    B.ID, B.ID_Date, 
    Menu =
        CASE S.menu_number
            WHEN 'Menu1' THEN B.menu1
            WHEN 'Menu2' THEN B.menu2
            WHEN 'Menu3' THEN B.menu3
            ELSE 'Unknown'
        END,
    S.date
FROM 
    ordering B
    JOIN menu_plan S ON B.ID_Date = S.Date 
WHERE 
    B.Number = '4000859'
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It works, but only one thing, without the row name 'Menu' it works: `B.ID_Date, CASE S.menu_number WHEN 'Menu1' ... END, S.date`. But how can I get the row name like Menu? With `Menu = CASE ...` it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the Case Statement. But it works only in this way: `SELECT B.ID, CASE ... WHEN "Menu1" THEN ... END AS Menu, S.date`

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT 
    s.ID, B.ID_Date, 
    Menu =
        CASE b.menu_number
            WHEN 'Menu1' THEN s.menu1
            WHEN 'Menu2' THEN s.menu2
            WHEN 'Menu3' THEN s.menu3
            ELSE 'Unknown'
        END,
    S.date
FROM 
    ordering B
    JOIN menu_plan s ON b.ID_Date = s.Date 
WHERE 
    b.[Number] = '4000859'

Comment: I think the aliases [s] & [b] are messed up within your query. Thanks for accepting my answer!